# DFS isn't being performed correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

I want to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-tree), but I'm stuck on some small part of the problem. Shortly, given a tree, every vertex of this tree has some weight. We define sum of a tree to be the sum of all weights of all nodes contained at the tree.

I have N nodes and I want to calculate the sum of the subtrees rooted at each of these N nodes. This sum I want to store in an array `res[]`. To do so I have to perform DFS and to sum up **correctly** the weights of the nodes. However, my DFS doesn't work like this and I don't know how to correct it.

**EDIT:** I've debugged my code, but I don't know how to correct it. It fails on calculating the `res[]` value for the leaves (for them it doesn't return anything). Also it doesn't calculate the right value for the internal nodes. I thought that I have to define new variable `int tempRes` in the `dfs` method and to return this variable, but at some point I have to zero it, and I don't know where.

```
package searching;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class CutTheTree {

    static List<ArrayList<Integer>> adj; //list which stores adjacency nodes, i.e. at position i I have list of the neighbours of node i
    static int N; //number of nodes
    static int[] res; //store the sum of weights of tree rooted at node i
    static boolean[] visited; //array which indicates if I have visited node or not
    static int[] weights;   //array of the given weights of each node
    static int W;   //this variable is not relevant to my problem

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line1 = br.readLine();
        N = Integer.parseInt(line1);
        String[] line2 = br.readLine().split(" ");
        weights = new int[N];       //weights of each vertex
        visited = new boolean[N];
        res = new int[N];
        adj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            adj.add(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < line2.length; i++) {
            weights[i] = Integer.parseInt(line2[i]);
        }
        W = 0; //total sum
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
            W+= weights[i];         //total sum of all weights
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) { //follow N-1 lines of the edges given as pairs, i.e. (1, 3) means edge from vertex 1 to vertex 3
            String[] line3 = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int start = Integer.parseInt(line3[0]);
            int end = Integer.parseInt(line3[1]);
            adj.get(start-1).add(end);      //store adjacent nodes in a linked list; substract 1 from the vtx id, since the indexing starts from 0
            adj.get(end-1).add(start);      //example: vtx 1 is a neighbor of vtx 3 and vtx 3 is neigbor of vtx 1
        }
        dfs(1);     //take vtx one as a root
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    // The problematic function!!!
    private static int dfs(int root) {
        int temp;
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> neigh = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //list of unvisited neighoring vetrices of the current node
        st.push(root);
        visited[root-1] = true; //mark current node as visited
        while(!st.isEmpty()){
            int curr = st.pop();
            if(isLeaf(curr)){
                res[curr-1]= weights[curr-1];
                return weights[curr-1];
            }
            else{
                neigh = neighbours(curr);
                if(neigh.size() == 0){
                    temp = weights[curr-1]; //if there is no unvisited nodes, return the weight function of the given node; however this does not work for the leaf nodes!                  
                }
                else{ //else I have to visit unvisited neighbors
                    res[curr-1] = weights[curr-1]; //the current res increases by the weight of the given node
                    for (int i = 0; i < neigh.size(); i++) {
                        int child = neigh.get(i);
                        visited[child-1] = true;
                        st.push(child);
                        res[curr-1]+= dfs(child); // for each unvisited neighbor I perform dfs and add the result to the corresponding index of res array
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
     //returns ArrayList of unvisited nodes of the current node
    private static ArrayList<Integer> neighbours(int node){
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.get(node-1).size(); i++) {
            int child = adj.get(node-1).get(i);
            if(!visited[child-1]){
                res.add(child);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this issue so far? Have you debugged your code to identify where and why it fails?

Answer (score 2):

Your `dfs` method returns 0 except for leaf nodes.

In addition, you seem to be mixing together a recursive and iterative approach. If you're using your own stack of unvisited nodes, you don't need to rely on the call stack provided by recursion.

Basically, you need to visit each node. In each visit, you add the node's weight to a single sum, then add its children onto the stack.

```
int result = 0;

while(!st.isEmpty()){
    int curr = st.pop();
    neigh = neighbours(curr);
    result += weights[curr-1]; 
    if(neigh.size() != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < neigh.size(); i++) {
            int child = neigh.get(i);
            visited[child-1] = true;
            st.push(child);
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: I added it because I had to return some int at the end; However it never returns 0 (because it stays in the while cycle) and for the leaf nodes I dont know how to update the information (it stays 0 in the `res` array) I dont know how to distigwish between cases when I am at a leaf node and when I am at internal node without unvisited neighbors.

Comment: Thanks, it is much better now, but can  you write where I have to update the `res` array?

Comment: I think this wont work, since you start addint the weights from the root. If this is the case, for the leaf nodes you will have weight equal to the path to this leaf node instead to the weight of the node itself

Comment: @user3371223 - I don't see how that array would be useful for the problem you cited. Is it your intention that each array member would be a subtree sum? Those subtree sums would differ depending on which root you started with. Have you considered iterating over edges, computing the (scalar) subtree sums on both sides of the edge, and finding the edge whose two adjacent subtrees have the minimum difference in sums?

Comment: it is not my intention, it is the best approach to the problem (I need it for later). My problem is that I cannot perform it. Now I have (almost) working code, i.e. it gives correct values for some nodes, but I have problem with the recursion. Can you check it?

Comment: @user3371223 - It's an undirected tree. Any node can be the root. The subtrees you encounter during the depth-first traversal depend on which node you choose to be the initial root, and the subtree sums do as well. Mixing an iterative and recursive approach is going to give you grief, especially when using global variables.

Comment: we always take the very first node to be the root. I know it is not well defignesd question but this is not the problem. I know that Im doing it very very WRONG but I dont know how to calculate `res` array correctly.

Comment: @user3371223 - In the problem you linked to, you cannot only take the first node to be a root. Consider the diagram in the Explanations section. You must be able to compute the sums of the subtrees (5,4,6) and (2,1,3). The sum for the subtree (2,1,3) will not be obtained when you begin traversing at node 1. But if you *really* want to go down that path - *warning: wrong path* - you would need to do a post-order traversal rather than pre-order. Peek at the top of the stack. If the top node has unvisited children, push those children onto the top of the stack, so that you'll process them first.

Comment: my problem is not which node to take as a root. I said lets take the first node as a root as an example. I will deal with it later. Firstly, I need to fix my dfs function. All other things are minor, that I can fix alone. What I really need is help for the dfs function. Obviously, Im missing some basic knowledges on the recursion and I dont know wehre else to ask or under what other form to ask my question. Can you please run my code with the exapmle given on that link and tell me how to fix it

Comment: @user3371223 - I did run and debug your original code, but it really should be you running and debugging your code. Stackoverflow can provide guidance, but it's not a code-writing service. I see your new code still has a mixed iterative/recursive approach to depth-first traversal. Pick one - iterative or recursive, but not both. Good luck!